# Why does MongoDB take so long to sort a result with only one object in it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am optimizing a fairly complicated query of the form:

```
db.foo.find({
    "$or":[
        {"bar1":ObjectID("123123"), baz:false},
        {"bar2":ObjectID("123123"), baz:false}
    ],
    "deleted":false}
).sort("modified_on")
```

And the sort appears to be killing my performance. I have indexes on the modified_date field like so:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "modified_on" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "realtalk.customer_profile",
    "name" : "modified_on_1"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "modified_on" : -1
    },
    "ns" : "realtalk.customer_profile",
    "name" : "modified_on_-1"
}
```

These do not seem to speed up the query at all. What is really driving my crazy though is the size of my result. There is only ever a handful of objects returned by this query, often only one. How is it taking mongo so long to sort one thing, and how can I speed it up?

Comment: At first glance, I noticed you have "modified_date" in your query and you've indexed the "modified_on" field. Was that a copy/paste error on this post or is that how the query is written?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but that was just an error copying over the query.

Comment: Could you post an example document please.

Comment: Actually , have you tried removing one of the indexes and checked? The order of the index i.e. -1 or 1 does not really matter. I think index can be used in both directions. Just guessing options as you tell index is not used properly by mongo. Feel free to point out if my understanding is not correct.